# Why does Remove-Item keep prompting to confirm?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

Why am I still being prompted even after using `-Confirm` and `-Force`?

[image: Shows PS console command and annoying dialog]

`PSVersion 5.0.10586.117`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [-Confirm documention](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849765.aspx),

> Prompts you for confirmation before running the cmdlet.

So you should omit the switch and just use `-Force` instead.

Comment: #FacePalm. My previous attempt was just `-Force` but that must have been prompting because it was a folder and I had not supplied `-Recurse`.

Comment: happens. Read the question and thought easy frag ;-)